# Prior For Gaussian R.V.s with Common Variance

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Suppose we observe $n$ independent random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$. Suppose also that the mean and variance of each $X_i$ is unknown. If $$X_i \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)$$ then a conjugate prior for $\mu_i,\sigma^2_i$ is $$\mu_i,\sigma^2_i \sim \mathrm{N\Gamma^{-1}}(\xi_i,\lambda_i,\alpha_i,\beta_i).$$ I am interested in the case where the variance $\sigma^2$ is common to all the variables. That is $$X_i \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2).$$ Does a joint conjugate prior exist for $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n,\sigma^2$ and, if so, can anyone point to references which might be helpful in determining it? Any hints would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for the existence of a conjugate prior, the likelihood must be expressed as an exponential family:
$$(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \sim \sigma^{ -n} \exp \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}
\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n (\mu_i-x_i)^2\right\}$$
Which leads to
$$\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n|\sigma^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\xi_i,\alpha\sigma^2)$$
and$$\sigma^{-2}\sim\mathcal{G}(\beta,\gamma)$$as acceptable conjugate prior, since updating to posterior means changing
\begin{align*}
\xi_i &\quad\text{ in } &\{\alpha^{-1}\xi+x_i\}\{\alpha^{-1}+1\}^{-1}\\
\alpha &\quad\text{ in } &\{\alpha^{-1}+1\}^{-1}\\
\beta &\quad\text{ in } &{\beta+n}\\
\gamma &\quad\text{ in } &{\gamma+\{\alpha+1\}^{-1}\sum (x_i-\xi)^2}
\end{align*}
or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. When going from prior to posterior did you need to write out Bayes' theorem or is there a trick to get the updated parameters in this case?

Comment: That's the whole point about conjugacy, when looking at the product prior x likelihood you can identify these hyperparameters.